# Find the file with highest numeric value using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have many files with alphanumeric names like

```
abc2,abc5,cat1,dog6,horse5,abc3,cat3,dog8,horse9,abc8
```

I want to find the file with highest numeric value and starts with abc. In this case the file I'm looking for is abc8 . I want a shell script to do this thing. 
Could anyone please help me.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please try something first, then if you face some problem tell us what you tried and what problem you faced and we will be glad to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
p=0; for f in abc*; do n="${f#abc}"; ((n>p)) && p=$n && of="$f"; done
echo "$of"
abc8
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
ls -d abc*|sort -nr |head -1
```